# How to do save and sync images at same time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

When I want save my post on posts table, I want to save images on media table too.
But in this time, I don't have any image id yet, so how can I sync them ?

I'm using many yo many relationship, and I have tree tables. (media, posts, media_post)

```php
--- (store codes) ---
$image = new Media();
$image->image = str_slug($new_name);
$image->image_path = public_path('images/'.str_slug($new_name));
$image->image_alt_name = $realname;
$image->save();

$post = new Post();
$post->fill(request->all());
$post->save();
```

So, I don't have any image id yet. How can I get them ?

> $post->images()->sync(???,false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the create() method instead of individually assigning the values and saving. This will return the model after it is created, so you will have access to the ID. Be aware that these fields need to be listed in $fillable in your model.

```
$image = Media::create(['image' => str_slug($new_name), 'image_path' => public_path('images/'.str_slug($new_name)), 'image_alt_name = $realname]);
```

Now $image->id will give you the ID of your new image.